# Настройка дебагера Go в Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, golang

Установил Visual Studio Code, поставил extention для языка Go. Написал hello world. При нажатии на шестеренку дебага всплывает сообщение:

> Please first open a folder in order to do advanced debug configuration.

Объясните что я упустил? Не понимаю о какой папке идет речь. В Go новичок.

Answer (score 2):

как Оказалось ларчик просто открывался. В панели слева есть синяя кнопка которая строит дерево в домашнем каталоге Go, нужно было ее нажать